# Pass 2 arguments in Handler javascript function in codebehind

Tags: javascript, c#, ext.net

I am trying to pass 2 parameters in Handler call in codebehind but I can't get it to work. Here is my code:

```
X.Msg.Confirm("Confirm", "The field has " + dependency.Count() + " dependent fields. Are you sure you want to proceed? (The dependent fields will be deleted also)", new MessageBoxButtonsConfig
{
    Yes = new MessageBoxButtonConfig
    {
        Handler = "App.direct.UC.DoYesDeleteDepField('" + fieldname + "," + dependency + "')", //ERROR LINE
        Text = "Yes"
    },
    No = new MessageBoxButtonConfig
    {
        Handler = "",
        Text = "No"
    }
}).Show();
```

**Error:**

> System.ArgumentException: DirectMethod: 'DoYesDeleteDepField', The parameter 'dep' is undefined at Ext.Net.DirectMethod.Invoke(Object target, HttpContext context, ParameterCollection args) at Ext.Net.DirectMethod.Invoke(Object target, ParameterCollection args) at Ext.Net.ResourceManager.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)

```
[DirectMethod]
public void DoYesDeleteDepField<T>(string fieldname, List<MyDependenciesClass> dep)
{....
```

Answer (score 3):

You are passing:

```
App.direct.UC.DoYesDeleteDepField('fieldname,dependency')
```

the way you written it.

To pass this:

```
App.direct.UC.DoYesDeleteDepField('fieldname', 'dependency')
```

you should draw the line like this:

```
"App.direct.UC.DoYesDeleteDepField('" + fieldname + "', '" + dependency + "')"
```

Answer (score 0):

For further information on this answer: the initial parameters were being read as a string, thus the javascript threw 'undefined'.

The solution works due to String Concatenation, which is a very important concept on OOP.

For more on string concatenation consult: How to [Concatenate Multiple Strings (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/how-to-concatenate-multiple-strings)